# Getting error: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, xsd

While configuring Hibernate I get the following error in my configuration file.

```
Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd)
```

When I check "More details", it gives me the following:

```
sch-props-correct.2: A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans,identifiedType'.
```

I've an applicationContext.xml file whose schema definition(where I import my hibernate-context.xml file) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

..
..
<!-- Imports datasource configuration -->
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

My hibernate-context.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
            ">
```

It is in this file(hibernate-context.xml) that I get the error.
My mind's blown and I'm stuck....how to get rid of this error? Kindly guide!! :(

Comment: Hmmm.  Your XML parser seems to be complaining about the actual schema (http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd), which is odd.  I'd have thought that it would be valid.  I looked at it quickly and didn't see any obvious problems.  Which XML parser are you using?

Comment: Hmm..I'm using Eclipse as my IDE. It's showing the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, the issue got resolved. I'm writing it here as future reference for anyone stuck in the same silly situation.

I changed this line from hibernate-context.xml:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
```

to

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
```

Beats me why, but it solved the error I was getting.

Comment: I had the same error too - I still don't know why the link needs a specific version number.

Comment: I am facing the same situation but in my case there is not hibernate-context.xml. Could you give some details about how did you debug the problem ?

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve the same issue 6 years later! Adding my solution as an answer, to be more visible. Voted +1 on both question and answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

6 years later, I had the same issue when upgrading from Spring 3.2 to Spring 4.3.

Even though I was using Spring Data 1.10, I solved it by changing to

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Issue with Spring 4.2

I fixed the problem changing
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
to
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.11.xsd